# command creation: floor crafting help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a command creation and in the third command block something is wrong

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add ink {Item:{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:0s,Count:5b},OnGround:1b}

/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add diamond {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Damage:0s,Count:4b},OnGround:1b}

/execute @e[tag=ink] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[tag=diamond,r=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[],display:{Name:"Morph Crafting"},EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Barbed Wire",Tags:["killitem"]}}}}

/execute @e[tag=killitem] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[tag=diamond,r=1,c=1]

/execute @e[tag=killitem] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[tag=ink,r=1,c=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `Tags` list as part of the squid's data for the spawn egg rather than the data for the item entity, resulting in no entities with a "killitem" tag existing (until the player uses the spawn egg). The fix is to just move the list over.

```
/execute @e[tag=ink] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[tag=diamond,r=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[],display:{Name:"Morph Crafting"},EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Barbed Wire"}}},Tags:["killitem"]}
```